# What is the dot in this vav?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, vowels-nekudot, miketz

What is this dot in the word יִוָּדַ֤ע in Mikeitz [41 31](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.41.31).

> וְלֹֽא־יִוָּדַ֤ע הַשָּׂבָע֙ בָּאָ֔רֶץ מִפְּנֵ֛י הָרָעָ֥ב  הַה֖וּא אַחֲרֵי־כֵ֑ן כִּֽי־כָבֵ֥ד ה֖וּא מְאֹֽד׃

How does it effect the reading of this word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [Dagesh Forte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagesh#Dagesh_hazak) which indicates [gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) of the consonant "w". So the word would be read something like *Yiwwadha'* with a prolonged /w/ sound.

The word is in passive future third-person masculine singular and means "[he] will be known".